# python add data to existing excel cell Win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Assume I have A1 as the only cell in a workbook, and it's blank.
I want my code to add "1" "2" and "3" to it so it says "1 2 3"

As of now I have:

```
NUMBERS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ThisSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = NUMBERS
```

this just writes the first value to the cell. I tried

```
ThisSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = Numbers[0-2]
```

but that just puts the LAST value in there. Is there a way for me to just add all of the data in there? This information will always be in String format, and I need to use Win32Com.

update:
I did

stringVar = ', '.join(str(v) for v in LIST)

UPDATE:this .join works perfectly for the NUMBERS list. Now I tried attributing it to another list that looks like this

```
LIST=[Description Good\nBad, Description Valid\nInvalid]
```

If I print LIST[0] The outcome is

```
Description Good
Bad
```

Which is what I want. But if I use .join on this one, it prints

```
('Description Good\nBad, Description Valid\nInvalid')
```

so for this one I need it to print as though I did LIST[0] and LIST[1]

Comment: If you want all of the values from NUMBERS then you seem to need `ThisSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = ' '.join([str(_) for _ in NUMBERS])`. If you just want the first three values then use `ThisSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = ' '.join([str(_) for _ in NUMBERS[:3]])`.

Comment: This is essentially what I did with my stringVar, and it works, except it prints the special characters instead of just the items in the list. So it prints \n instead of writing it to a new line. It also prints (' at the beginning and ') at the end of each item.

Comment: Can't help then since I don't have Excel.

Comment: Well it does that when I just print it to the command line, anyway. Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to put each number in a different cell, you would do something like:

```
it = 1
for num in NUMBERS:
    ThisSheet.Cells(1,it).Value = num
    it += 1
```

Or if you want the first 3 numbers in the same cell:

```
ThisSheet.Cells(1,it).Value = ' '.join([str(num) for num in NUMBERS[:3]])
```

Or all of the elements in `NUMBERS`:

```
ThisSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = ' '.join([str(num) for num in NUMBERS])
```

**EDIT**

Based on your question edit, for string types containing `\n` and assuming every time you find a newline character, you want to jump to the next row:

```
# Split the LIST[0] by the \n character
splitted_lst0 = LIST[0].split('\n')
# Iterate through the LIST[0] splitted by newlines
it = 1
for line in splitted_lst0:
     ThisSheet.Cells(1,it).Value = line
     it += 1
```

If you want to do this for the whole `LIST` and not only for `LIST[0]`, first merge it with the join method and split it just after it:

```
joined_list = (''.join(LIST)).split('\n')
```

And then, iterate through it the same way as we did before.

Comment: using this would work great if I didn't have new lines in my list. As of now it's printing \n instead of moving to a new line, and (' at the beginning of each item as well as ') at the end of each item. Any way of getting around that?

Comment: @nico do you mean that you have newlines in NUMBERS? Is NUMBERS of String type?

Comment: apologies. At first I was trying to get the numbers working, but I tried doing the same thing to a second List that has new lines. Every list contains strings, and no ints. The second List is like List = [Description Good \n Bad, Description Valid \n Invalid]  I can't provide the exact List due to restrictions, but when I print List[0] it prints Description Good and Bad on new lines. When I use .join, it prints ('Description Good\nBad'),('Description Valid\nInvalid')

Comment: Can you please update the question with this data, please? So using string arrays and with the expected behaviour when found a new line character.